# Potential energy of a compressed spring with uniformly distributed mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring, continuum-mechanics

Would the total potential energy of a spring with uniformly distributed mass be equal to the sum of the potential energy possessed by every infinitesimally small point along the spring? If so, would PE be equal to the integral of force times distance and therefore $U=(1/2)kd^2$.

Comment: Why do you think the distribution of mass makes a difference?

Comment: I'm assuming the PE at a given point along the spring depends on the point's displacement from the point of equilibrium.

Comment: -1. Not clear. You have not explained what effect you expect the distribution of mass to have on potential energy. You mention displacement from equilibrium but not mass. ... The formula $U=\frac12 kd^2$ and its derivation are found in any discussion of energy stored in springs. Why ask us to confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the spring is moving, the mass doesn't come into play.  Can I ask why you are mentioning the mass distribution?

On a physical spring, the mass and the spring constant may be correlated, but they are separate concepts.  The only thing that matters for the potential energy of the compressed spring is the stress/strain response of the material.

> Would the total potential energy of a spring with uniformly
>   distributed mass be equal to the sum of the potential energy possessed
>   by every infinitesimally small point along the spring?

Sure.  You can compress the spring (storing a specific amount of energy), then cut it into smaller (still compressed) portions.  And you can release any individual portion.

> If so, would PE be equal to the integral of force times distance

I'm not sure what specific integral you mean.  Each infinitesimal region still has a varying force on it during the compression.  I don't see what you gain by looking at a small region rather than the traditional calculation of integrating  the total force over the total distance moved by the end of the spring.

Comment: Since the distribution of mass affects the total kinetic energy of the spring, shouldn't  the potential energy possessed by the spring before its release from its displaced position also vary with the objects distribution of mass.

Comment: The kinetic energy of the spring itself is often discarded and not measured.  If the spring is moved slowly, the kinetic energy can be arbitrarily small.  In such a case, the spring potential energy is coming from external forces and the mass of the spring is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy is always equal to the integral of force times distance, because that is how you calculate work.

$$W=\int F\, dx$$

Potential energy is stored energy, and the energy put in ti be stored *is* the work done. In fact, potential energy is merely another name for the work done by conservative forces.

So yes, your derivation is correct and the formula you end out with true.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the spring in $\:n\:$ parts of equal length.Then
\begin{equation}
k_{p} = n\!\cdot\! k
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
where $\:k_{p}\:$ the spring constant of any part. If $\:x\:$ is the displacement of the whole spring then 
\begin{equation}
x_{p}= \dfrac{\;x\;}{n}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
where $\:x_{p}\:$ is the displacement of any part. Then
\begin{equation}
E_{p}= \tfrac{1}{2} k_{p}x^{2}_{p}=\tfrac{1}{2}\,n\,k \left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{1}{n}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\,k\,x^{2}\right)=\dfrac{E}{n}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
E= n\,E_{p}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}

---

<sup>**EDIT** (splitting the string in unequal parts)</sup>

<sup>Cut the spring in $\:n\:$ parts of various lengths.Then
\begin{equation}
x = x_{1}\!+\!x_{2}+\!\cdots\!+ x_{n}=\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}x_{\jmath}
\tag{ed-01}
\end{equation}
Since the applied force $\:F\:$ runs along all spring parts 
\begin{equation}
x=\dfrac{F}{k}\:\quad\text{and}\: \quad  x_{\jmath} =\dfrac{F}{k_{\jmath}}\:, \quad \jmath=1,2,\cdots,n
\tag{ed-02}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{k} =\dfrac{1}{k_{1}}\!+\!\dfrac{1}{k_{2}}+\!\cdots\!+\dfrac{1}{k_{n}}=\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}\dfrac{1}{k_{\jmath}} \qquad \text{(springs in series)}
\tag{ed-03}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}E_{\jmath}=\frac12\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}k_{\jmath}x^{2}_{\jmath}=\frac12\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}k_{\jmath}\left(\dfrac{F}{k_{\jmath}}\right)^{2}=\frac12 F^{2}\sum\limits_{\jmath=1}^{\jmath=n}\dfrac{1}{k_{\jmath}}=\frac12 \dfrac{F^{2}}{k}=\frac12 \,k\,\left(\dfrac{F}{k}\right)^{2}=\frac12 \,k\,x^{2}=E
\tag{ed-04}
\end{equation}</sup>

Comment: Uniform mass density has nothing to do with the validity of equation $\:E=\sum_{j}E_{j}\:$ as in BowlOfRed's answer and his comment under the question.